# Web application without entry points in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have only request/response handlers(servlets) for my GAE app. No front ends/entry points are needed. However I can't build/debug my app (in eclipse) without atleast an entry point class. 
Are entrypoint modules must for gae app? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GWT modules are not needed for App Engine.

Yes, they are needed for GWT. If you have a GWT app, then:

1. You need a [html host page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage). You need to have this page on your App Engine instance.
2. You need at least [one GWT module with one entry point class](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules). GWT client-side classes are compiled to javascript on your developers machine, then uploaded as JS files to App Engine.
3. If you use GWT-RPC (or RequestFactory) then you'll also need [server-side java classes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideServerSide) on your App Engine.